# Better or custom JUnit test filtering

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'd like to implement a better system to filter tests to run under JUnit in Eclipse. I'd like the @Categories, but not have to specify the list of classes in a @SuiteClasses({}) annotation , since I think that reduces the value, increases the amount of manual maintenance we have to do.

Is there some way to hook into the process where Eclipse runs JUnit test, to be able to do custom filtering on all the classes with a @Test in it? E.g. a class like this:

```
    @CustomFilteredTesting 
    public class TheCustomFilteredTestRun {
        public boolean includeThisTestClass(Class<?> klass) {
            // e.g. test whether klass is in a package or subsystem 
            // or a subtype of some interface. 
        } 
    }
```

Any help appreciated, -j

Answer (score 5):

Eclipse uses the default JUnit code to run the tests, so you only need to teach JUnit your new trick and Eclipse will be able to do it.

That out of the way: How can you split tests into suites without `@SuiteClasses`?

Tough. From my experience, there are several solutions:

1. Write a test that reads all suites and tries to find all tests and then makes sure that each test is in one suite. This test will let you know when you forgot to add a new test to the suites.

   Nice: No JUnit magic involved, will keep you safe if you forget something (like to add a `@Category` to a new test).

   Drawback: Needs quite some ugly File reading/code parsing/reflection mojo.
2. You can write your own test runner by extending `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`. That would allow you to add your own, custom annotations to classify tests and run them.
3. Add assumptions. `org.junit.Assume` is a nice little beast to silently fail a test. The test won't run (or it will run until the first assumption fails) but it also won't log an error. It's a bit like a smart `@Ignore`

   Write setup code that determines which tests to run and put `assumeThat()` in your code.

I actually prefer to use suites because:

1. The "do I have all tests" test tells when I'm wrong
2. I have a single place where I can see which test goes where
3. I can easily write more tests to make sure tests aren't repeated in suites

Comment: you can jump through all these hoops or just use TestNG.

Comment: I have some code cribbed that does the class discovery - will post it later !

Comment: Good effort; I don't quite get all of it, though. - What do you mean by 'The "do I have all tests" test'? Good to learn about the Assume thing, but how do I communicate the intention to run a specific subset of tests to it?

Comment: Is there an easy way in Eclipse to substitute your own Runner that applies to *all* tests, and which does not require a special annotation? Otherwise, "That would allow you to add your own, custom annotations to classify tests and run them" appears less desirable, since you introduce loads of boilerplate Annotations, into each test.

Comment: "in Eclipse to substitute your own Runner that applies to all tests" <== this is exactly what I'm after! ...hmmm...maybe if one was to define those classes that Eclipse loads, mimicking JUnit except...better. I'd be surprised if Eclipse were to do any extra checks...

Comment: **Eclipse doesn't use a special runner**. It just tells JUnit to run the tests!! So please forget about Eclipse. Just look in the JUnit documentation how to write your own runner and install it with `@RunWith`

Answer (score 3):

Consider using ClassPathSuite: http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp. We use it and define a Suite as follows:

```
@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@ExcludeBaseTypeFilter({ NotUnitTestable.class })
public class AllTests {
}
```

Exclusion is not possible using Annotations so we simply defined a marker interface (NotUnitTestable). We start our tests this way both in Eclipse and in our command line build using the JUnit ANT integration.

Comment: Interesting tip. Its main purpose I understand to be multi-project (module?) testing. I am not sure it solves the problem, though?

Answer (score 2):

Use [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html). It has test groups, you can see an example on front page. It has better support in parametrized tests. The integration with Spring through spring-test is better.

Comment: It seems that TestNG uses strings as identifiers for groups; e.g. '@Test(groups = { "slow" })'. That means they are completely separate from the packages and other things that are used to build an application. Also, I'd like to use something that the IDE can cross-reference. Eases maintenance. Do you know if TestNG allows @Test(xgroups=...) where one could use types instead?

Comment: Jonas: the choice of strings was deliberate to make it easy to select them with regular expressions (e.g. "Run all the methods that belong to the group "front-end.*"). Eclipse, IDEA and the HTML reports give you a report at the end that tells you all you need to do about what groups were run and not run, which methods belong to which groups, etc...